# Time attribute in custom product attributes

Tags: magento-1.4

I'm adding a time attribute like this

```
 $installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'valid_start_time', array(
    'type'                       => 'time',  // not correct
    'label'                      => 'Start Time ',
    'input'                      => 'time',
    'required'                   => false,
    'visible'                    => true,
    'searchable'                 => false,
    'filterable'                 => false,
    'comparable'                 => false,
    'used_for_sort_by'           => false,
    'is_configurable'            => false,
    'visible_on_front'           => false,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
    'used_in_product_listing'    => false,
    'global'          => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'note'            => '',
    'group'            => 'Valid'

    ));
```

Unfortunately,  while there is a nice input for 'time', there is no correcponding type. Replacing time type with 'text' or 'datetime' does not help either. What should be used there, or is some more complex solution required?

Answer (score 1):

The type relates to the EAV table where the value will be stored. Since this is a product it will then store the value in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` if you set this to `varchar`.

If you set this to `varchar` and the input to `time` you should be fine. Setting it to datetime requires a valid date as well and that's not something that will work in this case.